# How can I test styles from props in a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, tdd, enzyme

Good afternoon, I am a begginer in unit testing. I created a component `<CustomLink />` in it I use styled-component `Link`. I need to write a unit test using any of the tools (Mocha, Enzime, etc.) except Jest, which would check that the font in my styled-component is 18px.

```
export const CustomLink = props => {
    return(
        <WrapperLink>
            <Link fontSize="18px">{props.text}</Link>
        </WrapperLink>
    )
};
```

Styled-component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

    export const Link = styled.a`
        font-size: ${props => props.fontSize};
        cursor: pointer;
    `;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write unit tests for your styled-components with `jest-styled-components` library very easily.
like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import "jest-styled-components";

export const Link = styled.a`
  font-size: ${props => props.fontSize};
  cursor: pointer;
`;

test("it tests props", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Link fontSize={18} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toHaveStyleRule("font-size", "18");
});
```

you can read more:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-styled-components